# Suspicious facial expression and foreign object recognition using machine learning and image processing

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, face-recognition

I am stuck with a project on detecting suspicious facial expression along with detection of foreign objects (e.g. guns, metal rods or anything). I know nothing much of ML or image processing. I need to complete the project as soon as possible. It would be helpful if anyone could direct me with some things.

1. How can I manage a dataset?
2. Which type of code should I follow?
3. How do I present the final system?

I know it is a lot to ask but any amount of help is appreciated.

I have tried to train a machine using transfer learning following this link in in youtube:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avv9GQ3b6Qg\](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avv9GQ3b6Qg%5C)

The tutorial uses mobilenet as the model and a known dataset of 7 subset (Angry, Disgust, Fear, Happy, Neutral, Sad, Surprised). I was able to successfully train the model get the face detected based on these 7 emotions.

How do I further develop it to achieve what I want?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid this might not be the right place for such a question. Please refer to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)-section.

Comment: Then again, since you already solved parts of your project, you did answer some of your own questions already for yourself! You might just need to write another detection algorithm for the objects part. But without knowing anything about the data you have and more details, it is hard to give any advice. Sidenote: Facial expressions are to be handled with [care](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00507-5) in judging criminal intent. ;D